# Access master object record in trigger of child objectI have three objects

Tags: trigger, master-detail

1. Award
2. Users
3. Nominee

nominee is the juction object

and one more object `AllResult`

I want that when a record is inserted in `nominee` object, the same record gets inserted in `AllResult` Object as well.

For this I have written this trigger :

```
trigger MakeEntryInAllResult on Nominee__c (after insert)
{

    All_Result__C newEntry;

    for(Nominee__c newNominee:Trigger.new)
    {
        newEntry = new All_Result__c();

        newEntry.Award_Name__c = newNominee.Award__r.Name;
        newEntry.Nominee_Name__c = newNominee.Users__r.Name;

        insert newEntry;
    }
}
```

but I am getting the values of `newEntry.Award_Name__c` and `newEntry.Nominee_Name__c` as null.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Trigger` context collections, only the immediate fields of the object are populated meaning that the related fields (the `__r` ones) can't be used. Instead you have to query for the data:

```
trigger MakeEntryInAllResult on Nominee__c (after insert) {

    Set<Id> awardIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Nominee__c n : Trigger.new) {
        awardIds.add(n.Award__c);
        userIds.add(n.User__c);
    }

    Map<Id, Award__c> awards = new Map<Id, Award__c>([
            select Name from Award__c where Id in :awardIds
            ]);
    Map<Id, User__c> users = new Map<Id, User__c>([
            select Name from User__c where Id in :userIds
            ]);

    All_Result__c[] inserts = new All_Result__c[] {};
    for (Nominee__c n : Trigger.new) {
        inserts.add(new All_Result__c(
                Award_Name__c = awards.get(n.Award__c).Name,
                Nominee_Name__c = users.get(n.User__c).Name
                ));
    }
    insert inserts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I downvoted Keiths answer.  Yes, he is correct in that you need to requery to access relationship fields.  However, you can get by with a simple, single query instead of two queries with maps.

You'll also want to move your insert or DML outside of the for loop, as Keiths example correctly demonstrates.

```
List<All_Result__c> allResults = new List<All_Result__c>();
for(Nominee__c newNominee : 
    [Select 
        Award__r.Name
        ,Users__r.Name 
     From 
        Nominee__c 
     Where 
        Id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){
    allResults.add(
        new All_Result__c(
            Award_Name__c=newNominee.Award__r.Name
            ,Nominee_Name__c=newNominee.Users__r.Name
        )
    );
}

insert allResults;
```

Comment: James yep yours is a better solution.